# Install MikTex shared for dual booting Linux/Windows

Tags: miktex, windows, linux

I have a dual booting machine, and I want to be able to work on my documents regardless of the OS I'm in.

I can easily install MikTex in both OS independently. However, I think is a waste of space to have a duplicate repository. Is there a way to install it in such a way that the DB or other components that are independent from the OS can be shared and updated accordingly?

Comment: [`This answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15998/3954) from Martin Scharrer to [What LaTeX system should I use for an Ubuntu/Win7 dual boot environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15997/3954) gives the necessary tips.

Comment: That is exactly my question. Thanks. Should I delete this one?

Comment: If you consider the linked question solves your problem, then you can delete this one; other option would be to close it as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Well, I was looking an answer for MikTex, but I guess the process will be similar. I will try to do it, and wait to see if someone more experienced came with a solution, or if it is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

**N.B.** This answers the question of how one can prevent two miktex installs from occupying space with duplicate files. For a Windows/Linux dual boot environment, one should look at using texlive as per the instructions linked to by  Gonzalo Medina in the comments to the original question.

I guess it should be possible to achieve what you want by creating a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) to the path where you installed the repositories.

I haven't tried this, but I think the following should work:

1. Install miktex on both operating systems. I assume you have installed under c:\program files\miktex in both cases, and that each OS's C drive is mounted as D:\ on the other OS.
2. Delete the c:\program files\miktex folder in operating system number 2.
3. Open a command prompt in OS 2 and type

   mklink /D linkName c:\program files\miktex d:\program files\miktex

This should cause OS 2 to behave as if OS 1's install of MikTex were its own.

Comment: "Install miktex on both operating systems": Is there any place to get MiKTeX for Linux ? or using wine ?  .

Comment: @texenthusiast if one of the two operating systems is Linux then a similar approach should work, but I can't give full details because I don't know how texlive organises its files in the linux filesystem. The basic idea would be that anywhere there are duplicate files (e.g. package .sty files) you can delete the miketex copy and replace it with a symbolic link to the texlive copy.